# How do I host a SignalR hub in a WPF app?

Tags: autofac, caliburn.micro, asp.net-core-signalr

I want to self-host ASP.Net Core SignalR hub in my WPF (.NET Core 6) application. I use Autofac as my DI container and Caliburn.Micro as my MVVM framework.

Getting  the hosted SignalR hub to start on application startup works:

```
protected override async void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);
            host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => webBuilder
                    .UseUrls("http://localhost:5100")
                    .ConfigureServices(services => services.AddSignalR())
                    .Configure(app =>
                    {
                        app.UseRouting();
                        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapHub<RemoteControlHub>("/remote"));
                    }))
                .Build();
            await host.StartAsync();
        }
```

How do I get a SignalR IHubContext injected into my model classes? What would I need to register in my `ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)` method, so that my application class can do something like this:

```
public MyViewModel(
        ILogger logger,
        IHubContext<RemoteControlHub> hub)
    {
       // do something with hub 
    }
```

I can't switch to the Microsoft DI, so this is specifically for Autofac.

Comment: Are your view model activated by the hosts DI container?

Comment: Yes, my view models are activated by the DI container. I use Caliburn Micro with an Autofac bootstrapper to build up and wire up all dependencies.

Comment: The DI container or another DI container? It looks like you might have 2 of them.